# How do I find my 'datasetID' for making google datastore queries?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

How do I find my 'datasetID' for making google datastore queries?

This site is supposed to tell me how to query my google datastore: https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/

and it says the base URL is: https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets

the tutorial says to use a 'datasetID', so for example a full URL could be:

https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/12345/lookup

But I don't know how to figure out what my 'datasetID' is.

On the google developer console dashboard I see:
-projectID
-projectName

and under
Storage/Cloud data store/Query/

I see 'Entities' 'Name/ID'

but it doesn't say 'datasetID'

I've tried using the Name/ID like:

https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/5649323916754345244544/lookup

Then I just get the response 'Not found'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dataset id is the name of your Cloud project. Somewhat hard to find, but from the getting started guide:

> You have your  (same identifier as your Google Cloud Project ID).

So it will look something like:

> my-test-app123

In order to make sure you're not running into other problems (like authentication), I would recommend testing this through the API explorer site:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/datastore/v1beta2/datastore.datasets.lookup

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for your informative answer. I would like to mark it as the accepted answer, but right now I am getting 503. and "There was an error on the server. Retry the request." The request is something like: POST https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/961238231434015692/lookup?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.VwDo9Sgi3-BE1CEAAADasMidZrnvt9qT4M7juAIpWEUWw4CbOV-45gLoq7lM4vmTZzPAJcMCsxhpBqs5IzM
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer
 
{
} - is ?key={your_api_key} is supposed to have a real number in it?

Comment: It works now - perfect. I used the "Project Name" Located in the "Overview" section of my project. many thanks.

Comment: Hi Patrick, the project name as dataset id is working like charm. But in my case my project name is "domain.com:project-name", for this kind of projects I am getting 503 error. please help..

Comment: posted my question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062332/what-is-the-datasetid-for-google-cloud-datastore-json-api